# Magento2: Critical Issue: Emails are not sending

Tags: magento2, email

Emails are not sending to any users. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Any one can help me in this

Magento version 2.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Most likely all your cron are missing because one of your cron job has bugged and is stuck in the running status, this prevents other crons from running. What you have to do is find the cron job in the running status in the cron_schedule table of the database and delete the row.

But then if the problem persist you might want to take a look at that cron that keep getting stuck to see why it crashed.